# Creating images from text with Cloudinary, does not read style parameters

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I followed the example in the cloudinary documentation but I did not detect the styles, what could be happening?

My code

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.text("Sample Name",
            {   public_id: "dark_name",
                font_family: "Arial", 
                font_size: 18,
                font_color: "red", 
                opacity: 90 }, 
            function(error: any,result: any) { console.log(result) 
});
```

Example Cloudinary

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.text("Sample Name",
    { public_id: "dark_name",
      font_family: "Arial", 
      font_size: 12,
      font_color: "black", 
      opacity: 90 }, 
      function(error,result) { console.log(result, error) 
});
```

My result so far.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to upload a font you should take a look at the following- https://cloudinary.com/product_updates/custom_fonts